# Pasar un arreglo de JSON (ReactJs) a NodeJs Express

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express

Estoy tratando de hacer una API en NodeJs Express para consumirla en mi FE que está en ReactJs.

Este es el código que tengo en mi ReactJS:

```js
const params={ Accion:"Ver_XCosa", Campo1:txtnombre, Campo2:txtapellido }; 
        console.log(params);
        fetch(Api,{
                    method:"POST",
                    body:JSON.stringify(params) 
        })
        .then(respuesta=>respuesta.json())
        .then((datosRespuesta)=>{     
            console.log(datosRespuesta); 
             switch (datosRespuesta) {

                case "Los campos están nulos, no se ejecuta el servicio.":
                     alert(datosRespuesta);
                break;
                 

                case "El parámetro de Acción, está nulo.": 
                     alert(datosRespuesta);  
                break;
                
                case default:
                       asignar:datosRespuesta;
                break;

              }
```

Aquí el como salen de la interfaz (como los veo en la consola)

```js
{Accion: 'VerXCosa', Campo1: 'un nombre x', apellido: 'bananas'}
```

Bien, esto es lo que tengo en mi API en "router.js" que es donde se reciben las peticiones

Ahora, esto es lo que tengo en mi controller que se llama: "tsql.controller.js" aquí trae los parámetros que vienen de la interfaz ReactJs y de acuerdo al caso ejecuta el TSQL (SP) que se necesita.

```js
import {getConnection} from "./../database/database"; //--Se importa la conexión a la BD


const getTsql = async (request, response)=>{

    const {Accion} = request.body;
    console.log(Accion);
    switch (Accion) {


       case "Ver_XCosa":

              const { Campo1,  Campo2 } = request.body;
              
              try { 

                     if ( Campo1===undefined  ||  
                           Campo1===null   ||  Campo1===""   || Campo2===undefined ||
                           Campo2===null || Campo2===""){
                            response.status (400).json("Los datos  están nulos, no se ejecuta el servicio."); 
                     }
                     else{
                          
                            response.json(Accion, Campo1, Campo2);
     
     
                     }
                     
              } catch (error) {
                     response.status(500);
                     response.send(error.message);
              }  
              
       break;



       case null:
               response.json("Bienvenido a la API REST");
       break;

       case "":
               response.json("Bienvenido a la API REST");
       break;

       case undefined:
               response.json("Bienvenido a la API REST");
       break;
    
        

    } 
     
};

export const methods={ 
   getTsql
};
```

En loa anterior, estoy tratando de comprobar que estoy recibiendo los datos que vienen de la interfaz.

Mi problema radica en que quiero ver tomar los valores Acción, campo1, campo2 y no se porque no los puedo ver en la API. Los paso así porque quiero evitar estar escribiendo los diferentes tipos de campos y concentrar todo en un switch case para no estar haciendo una URL por cada solicitud.

Intente poner:

```js
router.post("/:{}", tsql.getTsql);
router.post("/", tsql.getTsql); //-- Aquí en la terminar si marca que lo encuentra, pero, al pasarlo al controller llegan como undefined la Acción y los otros campos no se como tomarlos
```

En la terminar de NodeJs Express dice que si encuentra el servicio, pero, al imprimir en la consola lo imprime como "indefinido". ¿Alguien podría decirme cómo tomar los parámetros o qué es lo que está mal?.

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Ya checaste la respuesta usando Postman?

Comment: En la terminar de la API como lo dije muestra "indefinido" / undefined. Si encuentra el servicio, pero, creo que mi problema es que no se como  bajo dichos parámetros a través de dicho arreglo. Tengo 1 hora aprendiendo esto, así es que mi conocimiento es muy reducido.

Comment: El primer case creo que estaría mal estructurado, porque entiendo que:

a) Valida las condiciones usando un string, sería mejor mandar un booleano y un mensaje en el JSON, el booleano para validar, el mensaje para mostrar en la alerta.

b) Tu acción por defecto sería hacer lo que se supone que debería hacer si todas las condiciones son válidas, que pasa si agregas otra validación y no modificas el código? Los datos van a pasar sean correctos o no. Podrías en su lugar implementar un aviso tipo "Esto no esta validado" para darte cuenta si algo esta chocando.

Comment: Por otro lado, la validación la podrías hacer desde antes de entrar al controlador usando [Express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs), la ruta quedaría así: 
`router.post("/",[check("Accion", "Acción obligatoria").not().isEmpty(), validacionRuta], tsql.getTsql)`, tienes que hacer un `check` por cada parámetro, donde `validacionRuta` es una función para manejar los errores:

Comment: `const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const validacionRuta = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }
  next();
};
`

Con lo cual simplificas la validación, y probablemente deje pasar los datos que estas enviando.

Comment: Gracias, por sus consejos. Pero, ¿Cómo le hago para tomar los datos que vienen de la interfaz en ese formato que les muestro?. Nota: Tengo, dos horas usando Express. Aclaro que el parámetro "Accion" es fijo siempre habrá una pero, los otros campos van a varias estos pueden ser más y diferentes. Porque no los estoy tomando adecuadamente o bien, llegan nulos.

Comment: Imprime solamente el `request.body` y comenta todas las validaciones que tiene/quita el switch case del controlador